Managing Cloud SQL user grants at scale
I have multiple Cloud SQL instances some private and some public (working on getting all to be private). I use IAM authorization on the databases.  The instances and users are created/managed using terraform (safer mysql module) . I have different groups based on different types of users (developers, admin) and therefore need different grants. I need to come up with a way to manage user grants at scale.
I was originally thinking about using a terraform module for managing the grants. The issue with that is that I would need to set up a bastion host (running cloud-sql-proxy) on the same VPC as the instance. I think I would have to use a local-exec provisioner to tunnel through the bastion host and then run the grants. I don't know if this would be the best option.
What are some other options that I may not be thinking about? Could something like google workflows be a choice? I haven't been able to find any documentation or articles covering something like this.

It's the problème of private Cloud SQL instances, and I convince that's a bad pattern. having a public IP is not a problème if you have the IAM authorization to open a tunnel and the IAM credential to log into the database... Anyway, if you have no public IP, you must be connected to the VPC, i.e. having a VM (a bastion if you prefer) to help you to connect to your VPC. Cloud Workflow is not a solution because it's not connected to the VPC. You could imagine deploying a Cloud Run job, with a direct VPC egress to achieve this and run your script in the Job.
